# SQL Server 2005 - Updating table in a one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a staging table that was created from a flat file and modified before copying to a final destination. Some of the records will be inserted and the rest updated if needed.

The only issue I have is it is a one to many relationship. The table is a list of retailers and some of them are entered with the same store name and SS# more than once but with a different contact type.

Like this:

```
Store_ID   SS#         First_Name     Last_Name        Type  Description
________________________________________________________________________
1234       123-12-1234 JP             Crawford         A     Owner
1234       123-12-1234 JP             Crawford         D     Other Contact 1
1234       987-76-9876 Aaron          Nola             E     Other Contact 2
1236       321-12-3210 Mikael         Franco           A     Manager
1236       321-12-3210 Mikael         Franco           J     Other Contact 7
```

I need to be able to select one of the records when there is a duplicate store_id/SS#. There is no date available so I do not know which record was added last. In cases where one of the records is "Owner" and the other is "Other Contact" I can assume the correct one is "Owner". Same for if one of them is "Manager" for instance. But there are some examples where one record may be "Other Contact 5" and the next is "Other Contact 6".

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you include any SQl you have tried.  Also, question, can it be assumed that Other Contact 5 and Other Contact 6 can be compared and ranked?  Is 5 to be preferred over 6, on the basis of sequence?  Is the `Type`  column relevant?  Is this post about how to update, or is it just that you want to pick the correct record from duplicates?

Comment: I regret your post is getting down-votes with no explanation.  Down-votes are normal, but we all need an explanation!

Comment: You want to merge data. We need to understand the data available in the staging table and the rules/logic that you want to use for that. As an example of the confusion, I don't know what you mean by "the correct one" above.

Comment: @Smandoli -The only SQL I have written so far is to update the final destination table. It does not account for this situation and I am not sure how to tackle it. The data being updated is primarily name, address and title. There is no preference to the contact types unless one of them is something other than "Other Contact." The problem is each time I run the script the record is updated with one of the two in the other table. So it will toggle between JP Crawford, a, Owner and JP Crawford, D, Other Contact 1.

Comment: @shawnt00 - Sorry for any confusion. The interface file that this table is created from is from a vendor. There should not be more than one contact type for the same person for each store ID which is why I used the words "correct one." I am beginning to think the best approach is to clean the data and have the vendor change the database/software so that adding a storeID/ss# combination that already exists will result in a key violation. I am still interested in hearing thoughts on how to handle this on my end however.

Comment: The table above has the same person listed twice (in two instances.) I thought the table was the target table. How does that fit in with what you just stated in the last comment?

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable simple task if we just had a full picture of all the behaviors you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the highest Type (eg A) is the one you would like to select in case of duplication, the following should work:

```
SELECT temp.store_id, temp.ss#, temp.first_name,
    temp.last_name, temp.type, temp.description
FROM
  (SELECT t.store_id, t.ss#, t.first_name,t.last_name, 
      t.type, t.description, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.store_id,ss# ORDER BY t.type) num
      FROM YourTable t) temp
WHERE temp.num=1;
```